# How to prevent datepicker help me change previous row value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have react bootstrap with datepicker function for each table row.
when I change first row is ok, but for second, third, to n rows it change all previous rows.

My workaround is to change ID variable to "" with BreakExeption -> {}, but it is not the solution.
Could anybody please help to figure out how to solve this problem?

Please see the following code:

```
    class DSRegisters extends Component {
        .....


        food_dateChanged(registerId, e) {
            var BreakException = {};

            $('.datepicker').each(function(){
                $(this).datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    language: 'th-th',
                    todayBtn: "linked",
                    autoclose: true,
                }).on("change", function(e) {

                    console.log(e.target.value);
                    var value = e.target.value;
                    console.log(registerId);

                    if (value) {
                    const [bd, bm, by] = value.split("/");
                    value = new Date(by-543,bm-1,bd);
                    }
                    Meteor.call('registers.food_dateChanged', registerId, value, (error) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error.reason, 'danger');
                        } else {
                            console.log('success');
                            throw BreakException;

                        }
                    });
                    registerId="";
                });

            });

        }
.....
```

and render()

```
                    <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control datepicker"
                            id="datepicker"
                            name="food_date"
                            ref={food_date => (this.food_date = food_date)}
                            defaultValue={food_date ?
                            (food_date.getDate()<10?'0':'')+food_date.getDate()+'/'+ (food_date.getMonth()<9?'0':'')+(food_date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+(food_date.getFullYear()+543)
                            :
                            food_date
                            }
                            onFocus={this.food_dateChanged.bind(this, _id)}

                        />

                    </FormGroup>
                    </td>
```

Thanks for both solutions, but I'm still facing the problem.
Below is the console.log() when I change each input.
Finally, all inputs are change to the last (07/10/2560).
[image]

When changing:
[image]

After refresh: 
[image]

The latest code:

```
food_dateChanged(registerId, e) {
    $('.datepicking').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            language: 'th-th',
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
            }).on("hide", (e) => {
                this.setState({ datePick: e.target.value });
                console.log(this.state.datePick);
                if (this.state.datePick) {
                    const [bd, bm, by] = this.state.datePick.split("/");
                    value = new Date(by-543,bm-1,bd);
                }
                Meteor.call('registers.food_dateChanged', registerId, value, (error) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error.reason, 'danger');
                    } else {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                });
            });
}
```

Comment: Do you really need an `id` for that inputs? If you're not going to use it, one quick option you have is to remove it and set the name as an array (name="food_date[]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.
It's about the binding.
I have on change function and after expression, I unbind it from change.
Please see the following code for my solution:

```
food_dateChanged(e) {
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            language: 'th-th',
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            forceParse: false
    }).on('change', function(e) {
            var value = e.target.value;
            console.log(value);
            console.log(e.target.id);
            console.log(e.target.name);

            // Process when value exist
            if (value) {
                const [bd, bm, by] = value.split("/");
                value = new Date(by-543,bm-1,bd);
            }

            Meteor.call('registers.food_dateChanged', e.target.name, value, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.reason, 'danger');
                } else {
                    console.log('success');
                    $('.datepicker').unbind('change');
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have initialize setState of each row item so it will be stored as a 'thing'. It is for in order to keep track of what you have selected.

Comment: Do you mean array? I will try again.